# Amazon S3 file upload

Tags: python, amazon-s3

Trying to run this code :

```
 import boto
 s3 = boto.connect_s3()
 bucket = s3.create_bucket('hopethisworks')  # bucket names must be unique
 key = bucket.new_key('examples/first_file.csv')
 key.set_contents_from_filename('C:\Python27\all_month.csv')
 key.set_acl('public-read')
```

Getting the following error:

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:       'C:\Python27\x07ll_month.csv'

How do I get past this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslashes:

```
key.set_contents_from_filename('C:\\Python27\\all_month.csv')
```

or, use a "raw" string (note the `r` prefix), which disables backslash escapes:

```
key.set_contents_from_filename(r'C:\Python27\all_month.csv')
```

In your code, the escape sequence `\a` is translated into a BEL character (also represented as `\x07`).